# Different form of posting messages on the forum

Tags: forum, phpbb, posting, smf-forum

Does any of the free forums (phpBB, SMF, etc.) allows you to select different required fields (to posting messages) for different sections of the forum?

Answer (score 1):

I know that phpBB does not have a way to easily change the fields on posting per forum (that is, not without a modification of the code). I'm pretty sure SMF and MyBB don't either. What you could do is add a conditional to see what forum the user is in (based on forum ID) and make certain fields required, but unless you want to go all out with an ACP module (or changing the current forums module to add this), you would have to hardcode it all.